# Using Maps on .NET MAUI triggers a unhandled exception in generated file

Tags: .net, maui

I need to get operating maps in my .NET MAUI app so i tried to use the maps from "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" but when i add the map control to the XAML it always trigger a breakpoint in generated file called "App.g.i.cs"

This is the source code of the XAML view that always throw that unhandled exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="RecargaEle.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <maps:Map/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</ContentPage>
```

I have tried this in .NET 6 and .NET 7 and it does not work in either of them...

The version of the libraries are:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps => 7.0.49
Microsoft.Maui.Maps => 7.0.49

I tried to change the version of the library multiples times and change the runtime and none of this have worked

EDIT: I'll add here the MauiProgram.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using RecargaEle.Service.Implementacion;

namespace RecargaEle;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseMauiMaps()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<PuntosRecargaService>();
        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exception? What is the error message it tells you? What platform are you trying to run it on? Does it work on other platforms? What did you already try? Have you added `UseMauiMaps()` to your `MauiProgram.cs`? A bit more information would be helpful :)

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Oops, i totally forgot about putting my MauiProgram.cs but yes, i added the UseMauiMaps() in the builder and it doesn't work, about the exception the only info Visual Studio gives me it's about there's unhandled excpetion and when i try to get the information about the exception it says is "win32 exception" :(
EDIT: I'm going to try it  later on other platform as Android to discard it's something about Windows platform

Comment: Well for Windows this error message is "correct". WinUI, the underlaying platform for .NET MAUI on Windows does not have a map control and as such, we're unable to implement it. We're working on a Windows one in the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit to have some solution: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/pull/604

It should work fine on other platforms. This error is expected for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I used Windows to execute the application. If i execute it on an Android device or an Emulator, everything works fine.

As @Gerald Versluis mentioned in the Commentsection:

> Well for Windows this error message is "correct". WinUI, the underlaying platform for .NET MAUI on Windows does not have a map control and as such, we're unable to implement it. We're working on a Windows one in the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit to have some solution: github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/pull/604 It should work fine on other platforms. This error is expected for Windows

Comment: Please add an explanation to your post other than _'Thanks'_ or _'I had the same problem'_.